# How to fix "The review is for an item of type Thing which is not a supported type."

Tags: schema, structured-data

How to fix this error Google Structured Data Testing Tool and what does it mean

**The review is for an item of type Thing which is not a supported type.**

Answer (score 0):

Google only provides rich snippets (stars) for reviews of certain types of things. You can see the list here:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

"Thing" is a catch all type of thing and also the default if you do not specify a type. You need to be more specific.